# jQuery toggleClass('class', 1000) toggles for only 1s then turns off, not toggles with a 1s animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

I'm getting a problem with jQuery UI's [toggleClass()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/), where if I leave the duration off, it behaves as expectedly, but with a specified duration, it only applies the class for the specified duration then removes the class.

The following code is loaded in a separate file (application.js) after jQuery and jQuery-UI:

```
( jQuery );
(function() {
    $('#expandingbox').hover(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass("hover", 1000);
    })
    $('#expandingbox').click(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass("expanded", 1000);
    });
}).call(this);
```

I'm using Rails 3.1, with Coffeescript and Sprockets 2.

Here's an example of my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/27rNG/

The behaviour I want is:
- user hovers over image
- image animates down a bit
- user clicks on image
- image ainmates down a whole lot

Am I not using toggleClass correctly?

**UPDATE**:
The usage was correct but JQuery UI wasn't being loaded correctly. I fixed this problem by loading JQuery UI separately from the Rails 3.1 Sprockets file, from Google's CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the documentation of a JQuery "library" called JQuery UI. http://jqueryui.com/

The method you are actually calling is JQuery's toggleClass ( http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ ), not JQuery UI's.

You can see that the second argument is not duration.

Here is a starting point for you: 
http://jsfiddle.net/27rNG/16/

Comment: Thanks! I thought loading JQuery UI right after JQuery will override the toggleClass() method, to accept the second parameter as a duration. In the jsfiddle link I had the JQuery UI loaded as an external js file. I'll do some more reading. Thanks a bunch for giving me that starting point!

Comment: No problem. I'm not super familiar with JQuery myself, and my start at a solution is bypassing JQuery UI. It's quite likely that your best bet is to get the dependency working rather than use my solution.